# How to change dynamically bottomAppBar menu icon

Tags: java, android, android-menu, android-bottomappbar

In my application I want to use `com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar` view.
I want show some **menu** items into this view and for this I write this code : `detailBottomAppBar.replaceMenu(R.menu.empty_menu);` , and with this code I can show menu items into this view.

I want to change **dynamically** the menu icon for one of this menu items. but I don't know how I can make it.

I can to change the icon with a **click listener** with below code

```
        detailBottomAppBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.detailMenu_favorite:
                        Toast.makeText(getViewContext(), "Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
item.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getViewContext(), R.drawable.ic_search_24dp));
                        break;
                    case R.id.detailMenu_comment:
                        Toast.makeText(getViewContext(), "Comment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

But I **don't want** to change this item **with click**, **I want** **open** `activity` to change the icon without the click listener .

How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure if BottomAppBar works differently from other menus, but can you show the code where you initialise the menu? Do you use `onCreateOptionsMenu`?

Comment: I used this methods `onCreateOptionsMenu` , `onPrepareOptionsMenu` but not work me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the Menu variable when you're creating the menu. That way you can get the specific item that you want and modify it.

```
private Menu _menu;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   _menu = menu;
}
```

Accessing the menu item you want

```
MenuItem item = _menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_id);
item.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getViewContext(), R.drawable.ic_search_24dp));
```

Comment: I used your code, but show me` java.lang.NullPointerException` error in `MenuItem item = _menu.findItem(R.id.detailMenu_favorite);` code. I used this code                 `MenuItem item = _menu.findItem(R.id.detailMenu_favorite);
                item.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getViewContext(), R.drawable.ic_search_24dp));` into `onCreate` method.

Comment: Is `_menu` null? Keep in mind that `onCreateOptionsMenu` needs to be called before you try to access `_menu`. If you're changing the icon in `onCreate`, then why not just put that icon in the menu.xml?